Using `with_structured_output` with ChatOpenAI wrapped in a LLMChain raises a validation error
The following code raises an error because the LLMChain tries to return a dictionary with two keys:
{ "page": "xxxx", "text": Card(name='Alice and Bob', description='An example card') }
but it fails to do so because the Card object is not a string. Is it the normal behavior? Passing a pydantic parser PydanticOutputParser(pydantic_object=Card) in the LLMChain instead of using the with_structured_output method works, but I wanted to use the implementation from OpenAI.
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import Optional
from langchain_core.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI

class Card(BaseModel):
    """Card data."""

    name: Optional[str] = Field(..., description="Character name")
    description: Optional[str] = Field(..., description="Character description")
    
structured_llm = ChatOpenAI().with_structured_output(Card)

prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template("""
    Extract card information from a given page:
    
    ### Page
    {page}

""")

chain = LLMChain(llm=structured_llm, prompt=prompt, verbose=True)

chain.invoke("Card name: Alice and Bob, Description: An example card")


It seems to be due to the depreciation of LLMChain:
structured_llm = ChatOpenAI().with_structured_output(Card)

chain = prompt | structured_llm
chain.invoke("Card name: Alice and Bob, Description: An example card")

> Card(name='Alice and Bob', description='An example card')

